# Work with protocol OAuth without browser?

Tags: mobile, oauth, protocols, authentication

I am a developer a large social network.

Does the protocol OAuth without browser? I plan to write desktop and mobile applications that can not use your browser to get access_token. It worries me step for get Access_token, I can not understand how to implement it.

Give examples of code if possible ...

Answer (score 2):

No, at least using the **common** OAuth flow (also called 3-legged).

You need to open a browser so the user can grant your app access to the protected resources.

You could use the 2-legged OAuth variation, but it's poorly documented and supported.